# Inject database dependency scala Object

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

Is there any way to inject play database dependency in Scala object? I know we can do it for class like

```
class MyClass @Inject() (db: Database) = {
}
```

but I want to inject dependencies without actually using Play plugin.

My build.sbt looks like this

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

lazy val sparkVersion = "2.1.0"

lazy val hadoopVersion = "2.7.0"

lazy val jacksonVersion = "2.8.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % hadoopVersion,
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
  "org.codehaus.janino" % "janino" % "3.0.7",
  "com.databricks" % "spark-redshift_2.11" % "3.0.0-preview1",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.34",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.4.6",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.5.9",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-jdbc_2.11" % "2.5.14",
  "com.amazon.redshift" % "jdbc42" % "1.2.1.1001" from "https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar"
)

fork in Test := true

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case ".gitkeep" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "META-INF/groovy-release-info.properties" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" => MergeStrategy.discard
  //case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
  case x: String if x.matches( """META-INF/.*\.(SF|DSA|RSA)""") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x: String if x.startsWith("META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

I tried

```
object MyObject {
@Inject()
var db: Database = _
}
```

but it fails for null pointer exception

Comment: From my humble experience: usually you don't want to store state in `object`. As such you don't want to inject state to object other way than just passing it in a method call. This way you have no initialization issues, no problems with changing behavior of injected dependencies and things are still testable.

Answer (score 4):

`@Inject` would not work in this case. `Object` works as a singleton on the language level, while dependency injection is configuration driven and in the case of `Playframework`, it's built with `Guice` engine underneath. Effectively DI works only on the objects, that are created by the DI or inserted into it, so `Guice` should at least be aware of the `MyObject` existence.

Best option is to use class with `@Inject` annotation

```
 case class MyObject @Inject() (db: Database)
```

If this is not the case, you can get `Injector` reference from Application object (which is ***deprecated*** and should be avoided)

```
object MyObject {
   lazy val db: Database = Play.unsafeApplication.injector.instanceOf[Database]
}
```

Comment: It throws me error as "Application not started" when I use Injector as you said

Comment: You need to have an application running. Do you have lazy before val db?

Comment: Yes. actually it's Spark application without Play plugin. But i want to use Play specific functionality like injecting Database, Configuration to read application.conf, Environment etc without actually enabling Play plugin in in build.sbt. so far to read application.conf I'm using ConfigFactory i/o Configuration. Is there any way to use these without using Play plugin?

Comment: I can inject depedencies if I declare it as Class. But to run spark job we need to have main method declare in an object otherwise it throws error. For e.g. I have class like class MyClass @Inject() (config: Configuration) and in that I'm reading all the variables declared in application.conf but I can't access them in main method of Spark application.

Comment: I would suggest having a static Guice context, where you can read dependencies from. You can instantiate GuiceApplicationBuilder, like it's done in Play, or create a separate modules as needed. Play takes care of running Guice underneath, if you don't want to start application, you would have to take care of it yourself

Comment: It can be as easy as new GuiceApplicationBuilder().in(Mode.Test).build.injector, you can drill down the code to strip of parts, that you don't actually need

Comment: so i tried lazy val db = GuiceApplicationBuilder().build().injector.instanceOf[Database] and it's throwing error No implementation for play.api.Application was bound.
  while locating play.api.Application. Is is applicable only for Play applications?

Comment: It uses general modules, take a look inside the method to figure this out